# AppAuth loopback authentication fails on macOS with Chrome

Tags: macos, oauth-2.0, loopback, appauth

We're using `AppAuth` for a macOS application to authenticate Google accounts. This has been working for years, except recently Chrome has started to block all `http` connections by default. The loopback server in AppAuth is hard-coded to work with http connections only. The following issue also seems to have gone unanswered: https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/624

What other options do we have for using a `https` loopback server on macOS for OAuth2 authentication? We need the loopback server to be able to extract parameters Google sends back after authentication. Asking users to switch from Chrome is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting - with loopback desktop logins there are two URLs involved:

- The URL in the desktop app, which is meant to be HTTP according to OAuth standards, since it runs on end user PCs. Using HTTPS would require the entire user base to host SSL certificates, which is highly impractical. Typically a loopback URL is a value such as http://localhost:8000, where the port number is often calculated at runtime.
- The URL used to invoke the system browser is a value such as https://myauthserver/authorize?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000..., and this should be HTTPS of course.

**PROBLEM DIAGNOSIS**

I'd be very surprised if Google have blocked this if you are using standard desktop logins, since it has been referenced on their [Native Apps Page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app) for years.

Are you sure something else is not the cause? One possibility might be lack of a user gesture in the system browser. Is the problem consistent and are there any differences in these cases:

- Make Safari Browser the default before login
- Make Chrome Browser the default before login
- Make Chrome Browser the default before login and clear browser cache

Let me know and I may be able to suggest some next steps ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what our users are seeing - they turn "Enhanced protection off" and it seems to work with Chrome as their default. Yes, using HTTPS is highly impractical for the purpose of Oauth authentication. I'm going to run some more tests at my end to see if I can reproduce this, since it's a handful of users and not everyone's complaining - which makes me now doubt my original question / complaint.